# Unable to create Lambda layer with python-ldap library

Tags: python, lambda, python-ldap

I am trying to create a lambda layer with python-ldap and I am getting error:

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.9" /bin/sh -c "/var/lang/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip; pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/; exit"
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /var/lang/lib/python3.9/site-packages (22.0.4)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-22.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 1.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 22.0.4
    Uninstalling pip-22.0.4:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-22.0.4
Successfully installed pip-22.1.2
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Collecting python-ldap
  Downloading python-ldap-3.4.0.tar.gz (376 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 376.2/376.2 kB 382.5 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting pyasn1>=0.3.7
  Downloading pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 77.1/77.1 kB 961.0 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.1.5
  Downloading pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 155.3/155.3 kB 23.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Building wheels for collected packages: python-ldap
  Building wheel for python-ldap (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for python-ldap (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for python-ldap (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [111 lines of output]
      /tmp/pip-build-env-ppz_5ubg/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:459: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      
      gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=3.4.0 "-DLDAPMODULE_AUTHOR=python-ldap project" "-DLDAPMODULE_LICENSE=Python style" -IModules -I/var/lang/include/python3.9 -c Modules/LDAPObject.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/Modules/LDAPObject.o
      In file included from Modules/LDAPObject.c:3:0:
      Modules/common.h:15:10: fatal error: lber.h: No such file or directory
       #include <lber.h>
                ^~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-ldap
Failed to build python-ldap
ERROR: Could not build wheels for python-ldap, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

How can I install pyproject.toml-based in a proper way so I will be able to create a lambda layer and use python-ldap in the lambda?